# Node requiring module before it's exposed is causing undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm ultimately trying to require `var server = require('../../index.js');` in my `foo-dao.js` file so that I can get access to a hapi server plugin without having to pass it through the hapi `request` object from controller to dao.

The problem can be seen in the comments of my foo-dao.js method when trying to require index.js at the top of the file.

I believe the problem is because in my index.js, it requires the ./modules folder which requires the ./modules/foo/foo-routes.js which requires the ./modules/foo/foo-ctrl.js which requires the ./modules/foo/foo-dao.js.

Here's a simplified visual of the requires

./modules/index.js -> ./modules/foo/foo-routes.js -> ./modules/foo/foo-ctrl.js -> ./modules/foo/foo-dao.js -> ./modules/index.js <-- PROBLEM LIES HERE BECAUSE MY SERVER VARIABLE IN INDEX.JS HAS NOT BEEN EXPOSED YET.

/hapi/index.js

```
/**
 * Hapi.js server.
 *
 * @type {exports}
 */
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var modules = require('./modules');

// Instantiate the server
var server = new Hapi.Server('0.0.0.0', 4445, {cors: true, debug: {request: ['error']}});

...

/**
 * Add all the modules within the modules folder
 */
for(var route in modules) {
  server.route(modules[route]);
}

/**
 * Expose the server's methods when used as a require statement
 *
 * @type {exports.server}
 */
module.exports = server;
```

/hapi/modules/foo/foo-routes.js

```
var Joi = require('Joi');
var fooController = require('./foo-ctrl');

module.exports = function() {
  return [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/api/foo',
      config: {
        handler: fooController.foo//,
      }
    }
  ]
}();
```

/hapi/modules/foo/foo-ctrl.js

```
var fooDao = require('./foo-dao');

module.exports = function() {

  return {

    foo: function foo(req, reply) {

      fooDao.findFoo(function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
          return reply(Boom.badImplementation(err));
        }

        reply(data);
      });
    }
  }
}();
```

/hapi/modules/foo/foo-dao.js

```
var server = require('../../index.js');  //  WHEN I REQUIRE THE FILE HERE, IT'S UNDEFINED, PROBABLY BECAUSE THE server OBJECT HAS NOT BEEN EXPOSED YET

console.log('server = ');
console.log(server);

module.exports = function() {

  return {

    findFoo: function findFoo(callback) {
      var server = require('../../index.js');  //  WHEN I REQUIRE THE FILE HERE, IT'S ACTUALLY DEFINED, PROBABLY BECAUSE THE server OBJECT HAS BEEN EXPOSED BY THIS POINT. I DON'T WANT TO HAVE TO REQUIRE INDEX.JS IN EVERY SINGLE FUNCTION THOUGH. HOW CAN I CIRCUMVENT THIS PROBLEM?
      ... get data and return it in the callback
    }
  }
}();
```

Comment: Okay, so make it non-circular.

Comment: @minitech Genius! Why didn't I think of that? Oh wait I did I identified the problem and i'm asking for help on ways to not make it circular.

Comment: Well, either every part of one component requires every part of the other to function, which is impossible, or you can break it up into more modules, or require more specific modules than an index if you’ve already accomplished step one.

Comment: I don't fully understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm ultimately trying to require var server = require('../../index.js'); in my foo-dao.js file so that I can get access to a hapi server plugin without having to pass it through the hapi request object from controller to dao.

This is a very clear indication of poor design that the CommonJS system is trying to save you from. Don't take a submodule and make it aware of a higher related parent model. It makes the submodule non-reusable and strongly couples it to the containing application, which is the opposite of what you want. Deep, reusable modules should get what they need passed in via options and request objects, not by requiring higher-level application abstractions.

Here's what you want to do in your `foo-dao.js` at least as a first step to solve your circular require problem. But even beyond that I think you need a more extensive change to your code structure to make it clean.

```
module.exports = function makeDao(server) {

  return {
    findFoo: function findFoo(callback) {
      //now via closure you have permanent access to the server,
      //without being coupled so tightly to it's exact filesystem location
    }
  }
};
```

To load this up, you'll need to pass the server instance down from the top, which in your case is to `modules`.

```
var server = new Hapi.Server('0.0.0.0', 4445, {cors: true, debug: {request: ['error']}});
var modules = require('./modules')(server);
```

This will make your modules code both easier to test (dependency injection) and re-use.

I elaborate more on my overall approach in my [express_code_structure](https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure) repository. In particular note how the `app`instance is passed down to the routes. Details of how this works change with express4 and I'm sure hapi.js is different, but the general ideas should probably still apply.

Comment: I didn't know you could pass variables into a `require` statement like that. How would I structure my code differently to make it more clean? It was VERY clean until I needed to access the server in my dao method and the only reason I need that is to access a hapijs plugin (Which i ultimately may not even leave it as a plugin since it's causing this much pain and restructuring)

Comment: I'm not. Look closely. The module exports a function. The outer code requires the module (which is a function), calls that function with some configuration, then then uses the value returned in the application. This pattern is very common and almost all express middleware (analogous to hapi plugins) use this. For example, if you want to limit upload size you might do `var limitMiddleware = require('limiter')({size: 100})`;

Comment: It's tough for me to give you concrete advice on the FS layout and code organization for your specific problem, but while there are legitimate uses of `require('../`, it's usually a code smell indicating you haven't gotten your separation of concerns right yet.

Comment: Interesting. Well i'm very curious about this with the Hapi plugin architecture. I know how I would do this without using a Hapi plugin and it wouldn't create a circular dependency, but I was just trying to use the plugin architecture and this might be a case where it just does not make sense.

Comment: I think i'm going to disagree with you that `require('../` is *usually* a code smell. It all depends on what you want to do. For example I have a constants file at my project root. I need to use `../` to reference that file. I also have a library that I created that is in my `root/lib` folder. If i'm working in `root/controllers/module/someFile.js` I also have to use `../../lib`.

Comment: Fair enough. It's your opinion. I think of modules like departments in a grocery store. They should be self contained and able to be converted from a subdirectory to an independent npm module without major surgery. I know TJ Holowaychuk has expressed ".." as a code smell although I can't find the quote with a quick web search. Nothing you say above strikes me a terrible, just use judiciously. I prefer to pass things in from above rather than reaching out to grab them.

Comment: Do you have a project on github that illustrate's your example that I could look at?